# Setting up publishing for Experience Manager

Tags: experience-manager, web8

when we hit below URL we are getting Whitelabel Error Page message.

```
http://localhost:8082/discovery-service/discovery.svc/Environment/PreviewWebServiceCapability
```

error:
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Sep 14 15:04:02 UTC 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

we have configured preview webservice in discovery service

```
<Role Name="PreviewWebServiceCapability" Url="http://localhost/cd_preview_webservice/ws/preview.svc">
```

is there any configuration missed ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't your PreviewWebServiceCapability also have a port? In my case I have the following:

```
<Role Name="PreviewWebServiceCapability" Url="http://localhost:8882/ws/preview.svc"></Role>
```

You're probably getting that error from whatever is running on port 80, and not from the preview service.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.However we are getting response when we hit URL http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/Environment/PreviewWebServiceCapability, is this correct ? will preview.svc not work if it is running on port 80. is it required to run preview.svc on other port ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The service will run in the port you configure it to run...